# Navigate through string and read parts of the lines into class fields

Tags: c++, string, substring, readfile

I want to substring my string into several parts. Let me explain what I've got and what I want. So here's what I've got, a text file that looks like this:

```
Name: 
Some Name
Country: 
Some Country
Info: 
Some info about me, my job, etc.
```

Now I read this file with this code:

```
std::ifstream t("file.txt");
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << t.rdbuf();
std::string temp = buffer.str();
```

Ok, it works fine, I have the whole file in my temp string but now I want to assign those special parts in my class which looks like this:

```
class MyPerson
{
public:
    std::string name;
    std::string country;
    std::string info;
}
```

So after I read the text file and assign it to the temp string I want to do something like this:

```
if (temp.find("Name:") != std::string::npos)
{
    // I need some code to read the next lines until i encounter "Country:"
    // so I can assign it to "name" from MyPerson
    // name = theSubstring
}

if (temp.find("Country:") != std::string::npos)
{
    // same as above but "Info:"
    // country = theSubstring
}

if (przepis.find("Info:") != std::string::npos)
{
    // till end
    // info = theSubstring
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Important note: it should be as simple as possible, no boost usage.

Comment: So your “name”, “country” etc records in the input can span multiple lines?  Unrelated: You can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) as a better alternative to immediately read an entire line of input into a `std::string`.

Comment: @5gon12eder
Ok, but I have the whole string in my temp variable so how can I write the next "n" lines from "Name:" to "Country" to the name variable?

Comment: you don't need to put everything in Temp in single shot. You can read from the stream in steps. But if you really want to read everything as one-big-read for some reason, then you can reads parts from this string with `istringstream` class. It's a stream that reads from the string you provide.

Comment: You didn't really answer my previous question but I guess that the answer is “yes”.  Read one line at a time, check if it introduces a new section and if not, concatenate it with what you have read so far.

Comment: But that would get you back into the streams. If you don't want that, you are a bit on your own. You can try splitting the huge temp-string by a new line character into an array of strings, and then inspect each item one by one. I mean, in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is always in the format:

```
header1:
one line of data
header2:
one line of data
...
```

Then you can safely read the file line-by-line with `std::getline`. Iterate over the input stream, read the lines in pairs so you always have full information about current "block of data", then process the block and read next pair-of-lines.

pseudocode:

```
open the ifstream to a file
loop {
    header = try to read 1 line from ifstream
    if stream is at end of file
        quit. done! all file was read
    if stream is broken
        quit. WTF!

    data = try to read 1 line from ifstream
    if stream is at end of file
        quit. what? why did it happen? DATA should be after a HEADER
    if stream is broken
        quit. WTF!

    // now you have a HEADER and DATA
    if header == 'Name:'
        myObject.Name = data
    if header == 'Foo:'
        myObject.Foo = data
    if header == 'Bar:'
        myObject.Bar = data
    ...
}
```

Just be careful with the stream-state checks, they are not obvious, and the code above is just pseudocode, the condition will be a bit different.

This above description does NOT require you to read whole text at once. It reads from the stream directly, and that'd be the normal way to do it. If yo uby change have the data as a string, you can "convert" the string into a temporary stream by `istringstring` class, and then read from it in the same way as above.

OTOH, if you insist on reading whole text and not using streams later, then you need to actually parse the string. You will need to first split the string by 'newline' character, store them, then pair them up, and then loop over the pairs and process them. Or if you don't want even that, then you can do it in one huge character-scanning loop, using three indices (oldposition, end-of-next-line, end-of-next-next-line) and process the block on the fly..